# Determining spacing by a number that is a multiple of a counter

Tags: spacing, macros, horizontal-alignment, margins, counters

I have `\hspace` and I have a `stepcounter` xyz

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcounter{xyz} \stepcounter{xyz}

\newcommand*\xyz{\stepcounter{xyz} \hspace*{-6.1em} 
   \hangindent=9mm \noindent 
   \textbf{\textit{\arabic{xyz}}} 
   \hspace{2.1em}}

\begin{document}

\xyz 
cbvcb cb vc bcvb cvbb c cbcvb cvbvbcvbvbv  c bvcbcvbvcbvbcbvccb cb vcb cvb cvb cv cbc vvbvbb b cvb cvb cb vc bcvbcbvvcv bcbvcbcb cb cv cb cvbcbvbcbdfgfgcbvb cvb cb cvb cb cb vcb c c bv cb cbcb  cbvc cb vb c cvb cvb

\end{document}
```

How to make A and B in `\hspace*{-A mm}` and `\hspace{B mm}`, be some multiples of the length in mm of the string `\textbf{\textit{\arabic{xyz}}}`? How do I define such variables and how do I enter them into `\hspace`?

EDIT: And how do I subtract or add Z mm as in `\hspace*{2\mywid + Z}` or `\hspace*{2\mywid - Z}`? The plus and minus are not working in this context.

Comment: If you want simple calculations with lengths, you can use something like (referring to my answer): `\hspace{\dimexpr2\mylength+10mm\relax}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a length variable.  Then, multiples of it are permitted.

Here, I made the left indent the same, and indexed the right indent by the counter value:

EDITED to allow a "+/-Z" shift to the indents, per the OP's request.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{xyz} 
\newlength\mywid
\newlength\myshift
\newlength\z
\setlength\z{3mm}
\setlength\mywid{\widthof{\textbf{\textit{\arabic{xyz}}}}}

\newcommand*\xyz{\stepcounter{xyz} 
   \setlength\myshift{-2\mywid + \z}
   \hspace*{\myshift} 
   \hangindent=9mm \noindent 
   \textbf{\textit{\arabic{xyz}}} 
   \setlength\myshift{\thexyz\mywid - \z}
   \hspace{\myshift}
}
\begin{document}

\xyz 
cbvcb cb vc bcvb cvbb c cbcvb cvbvbcvbvbv  c bvcbcvbvcbvbcbvccb cb vcb cvb cvb cv cbc vvbvbb b cvb cvb cb vc bcvbcbvvcv bcbvcbcb cb cv cb cvbcbvbcbdfgfgcbvb cvb cb cvb cb cb vcb c c bv cb cbcb  cbvc cb vb c cvb cvb

\xyz 
cbvcb cb vc bcvb cvbb c cbcvb cvbvbcvbvbv  c bvcbcvbvcbvbcbvccb cb vcb cvb cvb cv cbc vvbvbb b cvb cvb cb vc bcvbcbvvcv bcbvcbcb cb cv cb cvbcbvbcbdfgfgcbvb cvb cb cvb cb cb vcb c c bv cb cbcb  cbvc cb vb c cvb cvb

\xyz 
cbvcb cb vc bcvb cvbb c cbcvb cvbvbcvbvbv  c bvcbcvbvcbvbcbvccb cb vcb cvb cvb cv cbc vvbvbb b cvb cvb cb vc bcvbcbvvcv bcbvcbcb cb cv cb cvbcbvbcbdfgfgcbvb cvb cb cvb cb cb vcb c c bv cb cbcb  cbvc cb vb c cvb cvb

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I subtract or add Z mm as in \hspace*{2\mywid + Z} or \hspace*{2\mywid - Z}? The plus and minus is not working in this context. Also, how do I divide?

Comment: @GuidoJorg please see revision

Comment: @GuidoJorg For division, I recommend looking at the `fp` package, that allows floating point division.  Alternately, if you can find a clever way to express your divisors as reciprocals, then you can just use the current multiply feature on the reciprocal.

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to Steven's solution, but without using the `calc` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcounter{xyz}

\newlength{\mylength}

\newcommand*\xyz{%
   \stepcounter{xyz}%
   \settowidth{\mylength}{\textbf{\textit{\arabic{xyz}}}}%
   \hspace*{-3\mylength}%
   \hangindent=9mm \noindent%
   \textbf{\textit{\arabic{xyz}}}%
   \hspace{2\mylength}%
   }

\begin{document}

\xyz
cbvcb cb vc bcvb cvbb c cbcvb cvbvbcvbvbv  c bvcbcvbvcbvbcbvccb cb vcb cvb cvb cv cbc vvbvbb b cvb cvb cb vc bcvbcbvvcv bcbvcbcb cb cv cb cvbcbvbcbdfgfgcbvb cvb cb cvb cb cb vcb c c bv cb cbcb  cbvc cb vb c cvb cvb

\end{document}
```

[image]